# request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.21.35:443

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am getting this error while trying to *install* **expo init rn-first-app**.

can you please help me here.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

and then

```
expo init rn-first-app
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may behind the proxy, Try following methods.

1. You have to set your proxy in the environment variables as this image.
   [windows env setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUD9.png)
2. Then set your proxy using following two commands.

   npm config set proxy http://proxy-server:port

   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server:port

Answer (score 0):

Reason 01: make sure that your development device is connected to internet 
Reason 02: make sure you have installed `npm install expo-cli --global`

Try again by reconnect to internet